# Subtotal and Sumiif Issue in excel

Tags: excel

On the below image, how to do sumiif and subtotal?

[image: SubTotal and Sumiff]

Comment: Would you mind explaining how you get to the 14 and to the 12? And also, [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?!

Comment: @Peter This is what I am trying but not getting the actual value which I need after hiding the rows.

Comment: We are asking about the reason behind the values. What is the condition of your `sumif`

Comment: i understood this. What I dont understand is how you want to derive the 14 and the 12, i.e. 14 should be the sum of what exactly?

Comment: Ah, so you want to sum all visible numbers that do not have a blank next to it?!?

Comment: Yes I need to find the total of the cells which are visible and whose col A is not blank.

Comment: can you use a helper column?

Comment: then best edit your question - the "whose col A is not blank" is rather important in order to understand/solve it! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below formula

`=SUBTOTAL(109,B1:B6)` 
`=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(109,OFFSET(B1,ROW(B1:B6)-ROW(B1),,1)),--(A1:A6 <> ""))`

Comment: Thank you very much...It works perfectly even if rows are hidden..thnks a lot

Comment: @user2230817 You need to update the question as its seems confusing and will be helpful for other readers. It was a guess and happy it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem by adding a helper column. Place this formula in C1 and copy it down to C6: `=SUBTOTAL(109,B1)`.

Then in B7, use this formula: `=SUMIFS($C$1:$C$6,$A$1:$A$6,"<>")`

Answer (score 0):

One way is by using another cell.
[image]

Comment: you can replace `*IF(LEN(A1)>0,1,0)` with `*(LEN(A1)>0)`! :-)

Comment: yeah. there are multiple ways of doing 1 thing.. Though, thanks for sharing.. :-)